# select2 search preloaded list as typed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 on a select menu and when a user types into the search field, Select2 will search for those letters and display them even if they just appear in the middle of an option.  For example, if I have a select like this:

```
 <select id="e1">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="grape">Grape</option>
    <option value="prune">Prune</option>
</select>
```

My Select2 code looks like this:

```
$('#e1').select2({
                    placeholder: "",
                    allowClear: true,
                    width: '600px',
                    selectOnBlur: true,
                    scrollpad: true,
                });
```

And the user simply types "p" in the search box, it will display all three options.  What I want to happen in that situation is for it to just display "Prune."  Is there any way to do this?  I've looked around on Google and the documentation and either I'm missing something really crucial or it's just not there.  Anybody got any words of wisdom on the matter?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show us what you've tried? Otherwise, I'm not being paid to do your programming for you.

Comment: The question got answered, but you're right anyway.  I added what I had for me using Select2 in case anybody else searches for this problem and needs to see it.  Turned out to be obvious and stupid, like most questions are when one starts out.

Comment: Nice one, thanks. I've removed my -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to provide a custom `matcher` setting.

This is the currently default matcher function:

```
function(term, text) { 
    return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())>=0;
}
```

You could for example substitute it with

```
function(term, text) { 
    return text.substr(0, term.length).toUpperCase() == term.toUpperCase();
}
```

Example setup:

```
$("#e1").select2({
    // ...other options...
    matcher: function(term, text) { ... }
});
```

Comment: Aw, crap.  I see that now in the documentation.  I guess I was getting frustrated by the time I was getting to that point and just skimmed over it.  Thanks, accepting because it was correct.  I appreciate you giving me something instead of just being rude like some other answers to, let's say obvious questions, I've seen.